# Azure SQL Database and SQL Server PAAS - why need both?

Tags: azure

In Azure PAAS , When I create a SQL Database , it asks me to create a SQL Server why is this? Also as there are elastic pools why need a SQL Server?

Comment: nobody can explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure SQL Database and SQL Server PAAS - why need both?

Before answer this, let's see what is an Azure SQL logical server.For more information about Azure SQL logical server, please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-logical-servers#what-is-an-azure-sql-logical-server).

> A logical server acts as a **central administrative** point for multiple single or pooled **databases, logins, firewall rules, auditing rules, threat detection policies, and failover groups**. A logical server can be in a different region than its resource group. **The logical server must exist before you can create the Azure SQL database**. All databases on a server are created within the same region as the logical server.

So the Azure SQL server is the dependency of the azure database. If you want to create an Azure sql database, an existing Azure SQL server is required. It  is similar to a SQL Server instance that you may be familiar with in the on-premises world.